# how to add directory to sys.path on ipython startup

Tags: python, ipython

env:

- windows 7 English 32bit
- python 2.7.3
- ipython 0.13.1

I try the config:

```
ipython -i -c "import sys; sys.path.append('path_name')"
```

But it does not seem to work.
So what's the proper solution?

Or how to add current directory to sys.path on ipython startup?
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for my careless, it works.The problem comes from EasyShell of Eclipse plugin.And I still can't deal with Easyshell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of @cartman, I currently use the flowing config in the file `ipython_config.py` to add current directory to sys.path:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
'import sys,os; sys.path.append(os.getcwd())'
]
```

Until there is a better solution.

Comment: If you cann't find the config file, just run `ipython profile create`.

Answer (score 10):

just a little follow up to Honghe.Wu's answer.

One might want to add:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
'import sys; sys.path.append("/absolute/path/")']
```

to the ipython_config.py to add an arbitrary directory.

Also, if you are new to ipython (as I am) you need to create the standard profile first, so the ipython_config.py actually exists. So you need:

```
ipython profile create
```

and you can locate the configuration directory by

```
ipython locate
```

Best
S

Answer (score 1):

Put the command in the `ipython_config.py` file, see [Configuring the ipython command line application](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13/config/ipython.html) too see more configuration options.

Comment: but I want the path_name to be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

```
c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['import sys,os; sys.path.append os.get_exec_path())']
```

put this in the `ipython_config.py` file.

With the help of stevosn.